# How to view the HTML web storage in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, web-storage

How can I view HTML web storage in Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try the inspector in Chrome.

```
Right Click Page > Inspect Element > Resources -> Local Storage
```

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + I (keyboard shortcut Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: Is this just for the current website, or everything?

Comment: It is for the current website, as localstorage is bound to it. For chromium based browsers the local storage is now behind: `Right Click Page > Inspect Element > Application -> Local Storage`

Answer (score 8):

For Firefox use Firebug add-on. Open Firebug. Click on Console. On the command line type in:
`localStorage`

For development you can also edit local storage in Firebug using dot notation. For example:

```
localStorage.myVar = "hello"
localStorage.clear()
localStorage.removeItem("myVar")
```

In Firefox 19+ you can inspect localStorage directly from the console without Firebug:

```
inspect(localStorage)
```

This will pull up a panel displaying the key/value pairs

[Firebug localStorage documentation](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel#localStorage)

[Install Firebug add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Comment: Firebug with [FireStorage](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firestorage-plus/) works well.

Answer (score 3):

In **Firefox** the data is saved to the webappstore.sqlite in the FF profile folder. You can view it with the SQLite Manager, an addon for FF.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome pull down More Tools->Developer Tools.  In the panel that appears click the Application tab.  You will see LocalStorage in the subsequent menu.  You can delete, Edit etc....